# Android OpenGL app randomly reboots phone

Tags: android

I am developing an OpenGL application and testing it on Xperia 10 Mini (Android 2.1). After launching it and using it for some time the phone reboots (every time).

I have tried saving logcat to separate file, with no findings and also adb bugreport (I am not sure what to look for in that one. I found only some wlan related kernel Oops).

I am suspicious of opengl texture management or concurency. Here I am looking for any advice on how to debug the application and also for some tips on where to look for the problem.

Comment: I believe this is probably the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930602/camera-startpreview-crashes-and-reboots-phone-after-multiple-runs-of-activity

Answer (score 0):

Check your app for a memory leak. My second guess would be to check which OpenGL ES Version you are using (GL10 vs. GL20). The latter is not (fully) supported on Android 2.1 AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for a reply. I am definitely using GL10. As to the memory leaks, I suppose there would be a lot of GC messages (there are almost none). I will try to examine this further.

Comment: I have examined memory leaks and it seems application uses steady 2.4 - 2.5 MB of heap memory. I have also raised minimum SDK version from 1.6 to 2.1 as I have read there is no reason to develop against 1.6. I would be grateful for any other ideas.