# Camera.startPreview crashes and reboots phone after multiple runs of Activity

Tags: android, crash, android-camera

I have an `Activity` that opens the `Camera` and starts a preview on a `SurfaceTexture`.  Everything works fine, but I've noticed that if I repeatedly leave the activity and return to it, after a handful of times, the phone freezes and then reboots.

I've narrowed the problem down to the call to startPreview.  And I get two ominous log messages right before the issue happens:

```
01-19 10:20:52.038: E/IMGSRV(22777): :0: __map: Map device memory failed
01-19 10:20:52.038: W/GraphicBufferMapper(22777): registerBuffer(0x70b750) failed -14 (Bad address)
```

Has anyone seen this before?  Is this an issue with the Galaxy Nexus hardware or Android 4.0?  If so, are there any work arounds?

Note: My testing is on Android 4.0, with a Galaxy Nexus.

**Edit - Solved:**

Turns out it was a memory leak due to OpenGL.  All the examples on the web I could find use the following code to clean up after OpenGL.

```
try { mEgl.eglDestroyContext(mEglDisplay, mEglContext); } catch (Throwable t) {}
try { mEgl.eglDestroySurface(mEglDisplay, mEglSurface); } catch (Throwable t) {}
```

This leaks the surface, and as a result after some number of tries, which varies per phone, will cause OpenGL to fail to initialize.  For instance it would fail after 32 tries on the Nexus S, but only 8 tries on the LG Optimus.

After some trial and error I found that the following code fixed the issue:

```
mEgl.eglMakeCurrent(mEglDisplay, EGL10.EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL10.EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT);
```

Note: On the Galaxy Nexus instead of getting a nice OpenGL error which I could display to the user it just seemed to crash on startPreview.  I assume this was memory related, but the above fixed cleared it up as well.

Comment: To fix the problem did you do the eglMakeCurrent() call before, after, or instead of the eglDestroy* calls?

Comment: +Ed Burnette - Before.  One line before those other two calls.

Comment: Could you please tell where to put this code? I mean ``eglDestroy...``. Where can I get access to mEgl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SDK docs for the android.hardware.Camera class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) say the following:

> Important: Call `release()` to release the camera for use by other
>   applications. Applications should release the camera immediately in
>   `onPause()` (and re-`open()` it in `onResume()`).

Are you certain your activity releases the camera in `onPause()` and re-opens it in `onResume()`?

If you post a code sample, we would be better able to troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that release is getting called in onPause, and that it is being reopened correctly in onResume.  I can actually navigate out an into the Activity multiple times (which I wouldn't be able to do if it wasn't).

Comment: I haven't worked with SurfaceTexture, but I suspect there's some resource there you're not freeing/releasing in onPause().  Perhaps a Bitmap or some other bit of graphics-related memory.  The error message in logcat is clearly complaining that memory is not available.

Comment: SurfaceTexture has a public method called release(), documented as "release() frees all the buffers and puts the SurfaceTexture into the 'abandoned' state."  Are you calling that in your onPause()?

Comment: That's a good point.  I'll run a memory trace on it and see if I can find any objects that aren't getting cleaned up.

Comment: I marked your solution as correct, because you're comments on it being a memory related issue were what led me down the right path to the solution.  See above for more details on what was going on.

Comment: Glad I could help, and congrats on finding the true root cause of the problem.